# RDP connection list in HKEY_CURRENT_USER reverts to previous state after reboot

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, windows-registry, remote-access

It's a rather weird issue I've never seen before:

I have many obsolete stuff in my recent connection list in **mstsc** and want to delete it. I successfully deleted the obsolete items from the registry, and I do not see them in RDP anymore after that. However, after a reboot the old values appear in the registry again (even before starting RDP), and RDP shows the old items again.

**mstsc before reboot**

[image]

**mstsc after reboot**

[image]

I delete it via following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default
```

**registry key before reboot**

[image]

**registry key after reboot** (before even starting RDP again)

[image]

I cannot figure out the source from where connections are fetched again.

I searched for other occurrences and found only one more place where they appeared: `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-839268265-2293069135-1424177623-1000\So‌‌​​ftware\Microsoft\Te‌​r‌​minal Server Client\Servers`, but they are similar to the (cleaned) list in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, no obsolete entries I see each time after reboot.

Comment: Yes, exactly. What *other occurrences* should I search for?

Comment: And I assume you exited RDP before deleting from the registry? (So, RDP itself should not have the old values in memory, even when it might not show them anymore, so it cannot write them back to the registry upon exiting.)

Comment: I searched for occurrences and found only one more place where they appeared: *HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-839268265-2293069135-1424177623-1000\So‌​ftware\Microsoft\Ter‌​minal Server Client\Servers*, but they are similar to the (cleaned) list in *HKEY_CURRENT_USER*, no obsolete entries I see each time after reboot.

Comment: I mistakenly appended `/Addins`, corrected just now.

Comment: @Arjan, added screens to answer your questions. After reboot the registry shows the same disregard RDP was started or not.

Comment: No more questions from me ;-) (Though I'm curious about other registry items, like the recent list in Notepad...) Let's remove our outdated comments?

Comment: Let it be, will check about other recents

Comment: @Arjan, the problem disappeared itself)) I have no idea what was the reason. Maybe registry branch was locked by smth.